# Is there any way to get another element value in Less?

Tags: css, less

I'm new to `Less`.

In my script, I'd like to use the `width` of `box1` in `box2`.

Please review my script.

```
#box1
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}
#box2
{
    width: #box1.width - 100px;
}
```

Is it possible or not? If yes, please give me correct `Less` code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unfortunatly it is indeed not possible. You could work with variables and do something like this however:

```
@box1width: 1000px;
#box1
{
    width: @box1width;
    height: 500px;
}
#box2
{
    width: @box1width - 100;
}
```

Comment: I don't like the "indeed" part because it could have been implemented easily as you can already import the whole block using `#box1();` inside of the `#box2` block.

Comment: @PetrPeller that is 'indeed' possible, but how would you set the width of `#box2` based on the width of `#box1`. There is no way to access a single property form that selector (to my knowledge).

Comment: @Pevara I'm woundering if itspossible to include values of pseude element like 
e.g.  .icon-calendar:before() 
is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. LESS processes the style sheet to produce CSS, and it doesn't have any knowledge of the elements in the page.

What you are looking for is [CSS Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but that was only supported in Internet Explorer, and support for that was dropped in IE8.