# How can I get height of any element using LESS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

How can I get height of any element using LESS?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    header {
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        background: red;
    }

    @windowHeight: `$(window).height()`;
    @headerHeight: `$('header').height()`; /* NOT WORKING */

    @sectionHeight: @windowHeight - @headerHeight;

    section {
        height: ~'@{sectionHeight}px';
        text-align: center;
        background: green;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <header>TITLE<header>

    <section>TEXT</section>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get height of any element using LESS?

Example if I set `<header>` `height = 100px`, then this code is working

Comment: This is not possible in LESS. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778100/is-there-any-way-to-get-another-element-value-in-less).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since LESS processes your styles BEFORE the CSS gets delivered and interpreted by the browser there is no way you can let it do the math after that. The information needed is rendered way later, so you will have to either include a JS to modify the DOM after loading or make JS build the section in the first place.